# jQuery .val() is returning an empty string for input element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, haml

I have a few input elements in a div and I am trying to use jQuery to 1) check the content of the first input, and if it is not blank, then show the next input, and so on. However, the problem I have is no matter what I type into the input box, .val() returns an empty string in the browser console.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <span class="team-member-form" id="team-member-1-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"></input>
    <br/>
  <span class="team-member-form" id="team-member-2-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"></input>
    <br/>
  <span class="team-member-form" id="team-member-3-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"></input>
    <br/>
  <span class="team-member-form" id="team-member-4-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"></input>
    <br/>
  <span class="team-member-form" id="team-member-5-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"></input>
    <br/>
  
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $('.team-member-form').on('keyup', function() {
                var teamMemberForm = $(this).attr('id');
                var teamMemberNumber = teamMemberForm.split('-')[2];
                var teamMemberFormValue = $(this).val();
                console.log(teamMemberFormValue);
```

So no matter what I type into the input, the console.log is just an empty string. Any ideas why?

Comment: `.team-member-form` is a `<span>` element, which never has a value.

Comment: You are selecting the wrong element.
The selector would be `.form-control` instead of `.team-member-form`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider using `.next()` to select the proper `input` element.

Comment: FYI: `input` elements do not get closed. There is no such thing as `</input>`. Conversely, `span` elements must be closed - - you do not have any `</span>` tags in the supplied code.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I was targeting the span element, thanks! As for the closing tags, I'm actually using HAML (no closing tags) so I just used a quick converter online and didn't notice it had an issue with the tags. Thanks!

Comment: Also, just as another tip, consider using the `input` event instead of the `keyup` event as it works more reliably across various device types, and is also fired when the user copies in content using the mouse, where `keyup` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to attach the `keyup` event to the input element.
Currently it is attached to the `span`.

I have included a code snippet that is binding the `keyup` to the `.form-control` instead.

```js
$('.team-member-form .form-control').on('keyup', function() {
  var teamMemberFormValue = $(this).val();
  console.log(teamMemberFormValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <span class="team-member-form" id="team-member-1-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"></input>
    <br/>
  <span class="team-member-form" id="team-member-2-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"></input>
    <br/>
  <span class="team-member-form" id="team-member-3-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"></input>
    <br/>
  <span class="team-member-form" id="team-member-4-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"></input>
    <br/>
  <span class="team-member-form" id="team-member-5-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"></input>
    <br/>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.team-member-form > input').on('keyup', function() {
    var teamMemberForm = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var teamMemberNumber = teamMemberForm.split('-')[2];
    var teamMemberFormValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(teamMemberFormValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="team-member-form" id="team-member-1-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="team-member-form" id="team-member-2-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="team-member-form" id="team-member-3-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="team-member-form" id="team-member-4-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="team-member-form" id="team-member-5-form">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

You had poor HTML Code practices. Your `<span>` tags were open, yet not closed. You also had closing tags for `<input>` when they are not required. I changed them to `<div>` and cleaned up the HTML First.

Now for the jQuery, we adjust the selector first, to select the `<input>` element. This will help `keyup` event yet give `this` a different reference. We can use `.parent()` to select the parent element and get the `id` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to use jQuery you could also do it with pure JS

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.team-member-form .form-control').forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    console.log(e.value)
  })
})
```